# ¿Como puedo imprimir 10 decimales en c++?

Tags: c++

Solo necesito siempre imprimir 10 decimales.
Intenté esto pero la verdad como soy autodidacta y principiante no sé porqué no funciona

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    long double x=0.0000000000;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

Si mando 1.2377743483, el programa imprime 1.23777

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El código en preguntas y respuestas va como texto (nadie te va a responder con una imagen pa ponerte a transcribir). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma sencilla es con [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    long double a, b;
    a = 1.2377743483;
    b = 37.0/3.0;
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << b;
    return 0;
}
```

La salida:

```
1.2377743483
12.3333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a necesitar definir como fixed y usar setPrecision.
Cuando se especifica como fixed, los valores de punto flotante se expresan usando la notación de punto fijo, el valor se representa con exactamente la cantidad de dígitos especificada en el campo precisión (precision) sin parte exponente.

#### Notación fija

Es la notación tradicional, que vemos en la escuela básica por así decirlo, donde el divisor decimal se ubica visualmente exactamente donde separa la parte entera de la decimal.

Ejemplos:

3.14159

1024.00

1.00001

#### Ejemplo notación científica

Es una notación más parecida a lo que hace la computadora con el punto flotante, generalmente dejando un solo lugar para el dígito principal, y usando un exponencial para indicar cuántos "lugares" se corre el separador decimal.

Ejemplos:

3.14159e+000

1.024e+003

1.00001e+000

#### Implementación

```
cout << setprecision(10) << fixed << x;
```

Siendo x tu variable en este caso

#### Código adaptado

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long double x=0.0000000000;
    cin>>x;
    cout << setprecision(10) << fixed << x;
    return 0;
}
```