# borrar ceros a la hora de almacenar dato de tipo double c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

una consulta algo novata, estoy almacenando en una variable de tipo double un salario básicamente porque puedo guardarlo con decimales, pasa que cuando creo una variable de tipo double

```
double SalarioMensual;

        cout<<"Ingrese su Ingreso Mensual:"<<endl;
        cin>>salarioMensual;
```

pasa que si yo ingreso 100.000 me agrega 0 de más, alguien podría ayudarme a solucionar ese problema que nose porque pasa, me gustaría que respetara los 0 que le pongo o los dígitos que le pongo, porque siempre me agrega 0 de más.

también me pasa cuando el double lo intento pasar a string se me guarda con muchos 0 que no deberia tener

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo definir la precisión de un double en C ++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/165171/c%c3%b3mo-definir-la-precisi%c3%b3n-de-un-double-en-c) o [¿Como puedo imprimir 10 decimales en c++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/507729/169744)

Comment: parece que mi pregunta es otra entonces