# Como poner imprimir números decimales siempre después de la coma en c++?

Tags: c++

tengo un trabajo en el cual necesito que los resultados me aparezcan siempre con dos dígitos después de la coma, pero cuando lo hago, si el número es entero no me muestra ningún número después de la coma. ej:

```
double notaA, notaB, notaC, media;
cout << "Dame la nota A: ";
cin >> notaA;
cout << "Dame la nota B: ";
cin >> notaB;
cout << "Dame la nota C: ";
cin >> notaC;
notaA = (notaA*2)/10;
notaB = (notaB*3)/10;
notaC = (notaC*5)/10;
media = notaA+notaB+notaC;
cout << endl 
    << "MEDIA = "
    << media;
cout.precision(1);

return 0;
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como puedo imprimir 10 decimales en c++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/507729/como-puedo-imprimir-10-decimales-en-c)

Answer (score 2):

Guiándome de las respuestas de [**ésta pregunta**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515592/how-to-use-setprecision-in-c), puedes hacerlo con la función [**`setprecision(2)`**](https://cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) para que el valor tenga 2 decimales. Para usarlo debes importar la librería `<iomanip>` y utilizarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
cout << endl << "MEDIA = " << fixed << setprecision(2) << media;
```

Ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double notaA, notaB, notaC, media;
    cout << "Dame la nota A: ";
    cin >> notaA;
    cout << "Dame la nota B: ";
    cin >> notaB;
    cout << "Dame la nota C: ";
    cin >> notaC;

    notaA = (notaA * 2) / 10;
    notaB = (notaB * 3) / 10;
    notaC = (notaC * 5) / 10;

    media = notaA + notaB + notaC;

    cout << endl << "MEDIA = " << fixed << setprecision(2) << media;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
// Dame la nota A: 12.4
// Dame la nota B: 12
// Dame la nota C: 9.2

// MEDIA = 10.68

// ======================

// Dame la nota A: 10
// Dame la nota B: 10
// Dame la nota C: 10

// MEDIA = 10.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Antes de [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) la única manera de controlar los decimales a mostrar era con la cabecera [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) que permite usar [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
auto f = 1.f / .7f;

std::cout << f << '\n';
std::cout << std::fixed << f << '\n';
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << f << '\n';
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 1.42857
> 1.428571
> 1.43
> ```

A partir de [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) puedes usar [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), con un uso algo más intuitivo:

```
auto f = 1.f / .7f;

std::cout << std::format("{}\n", f);
std::cout << std::format("{:.2f}\n", f);
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 1.4285715
> 1.43
> ```

A partir de [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) puedes usar [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print), que funciona igual que `std::format` pero va directamente a la consola en lugar de devolver el texto formateado:

```
auto f = 1.f / .7f;

std::print("{}\n", f);
std::print("{:.2f}\n", f);
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 1.4285715
> 1.43
> ```

Comment: Y como puedo usar c++20 o cualquier otra version en mis programas ?

Comment: @Eipo eso dependerá del [IDE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entorno_de_desarrollo_integrado) que estés usando. Pero uses el que uses `std::print` aún (03/04/2023) no está implementado en la mayoría de compiladores.